# TinyMCE 6 - font size option not showing

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

I'm using TinyMCE 6.0.3 and the fontsizeselect option doesn't show.  Here is my initialization:

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#txtServiceDscr',
        menubar: false,        
        toolbar: 'fontsizeselect | forecolor'
    });
```

The forecolor option is visible, but fontsizeselect isn't:

[image]

... there are no errors in the console.  Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `fontsizeselect` toolbar button was renamed in TinyMCE 6 to make it more consistent. It's now just called `fontsize`, so if you change your configuration to that then it should work.

There were a number of other renamed or changed things in TinyMCE 6 as well, so I'd suggest checking out the migration guide: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/migration-from-5x/#things-we-renamed